# WFS: how to do relative dates?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature, datetime

How would you query a WFS using relative dates/ranges in a single URL call?

For example, I can do this:

```
https://my.server/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=domain:dataset&outputFormat=application/json&count=50&cql_filter=(timefield DURING 2019-01-01T00:00:00/2019-01-10T00:00:00) AND ...
```

This is fine for discrete queries but not for subscription services.  If I want to pull "today" minus 365 days, how would I do that?

Comment: If you can calculate what date is now - 365, you should be able to use the Filter Encoding `BegunBy` temporal operator

Comment: Yep, easily done with Python. I'm looking to do this entirely in a URL to feed into an ArcGIS Online map for someone who does not have access to run scripts.

Comment: I understand you want to make it as a single request, the question is whether you can calculate for the request the time you want have as the date-365, or whether you only have the now date.

Comment: It will have to be a fixed duration with a generic stop.  I have no ISO-8601 date(s) to use as an input.  As @ian-turton commented below it would have to be something like `P1Y/PRESENT` - except WFS doesn't seem to like that.

Answer (score 1):

In WMS you can use `P1Y/PRESENT`, you may be able to use a similar format in a WFS CQL query.

**UPDATE**

Looking at the ECQL documentation, it seems as though PRESENT is part of the WMS spec not the ECQL one but you can use a filter like:

```
time during P1Y / 2019-03-09T00:00:00Z
```

Which will be converted internally to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fes:Filter xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
 <fes:During>
   <fes:ValueReference>time</fes:ValueReference>
   <fes:Literal>Period{begin:Instant{position:Position{Fri Mar 09 00:00:00 GMT 2018}}, end:Instant{position:Position{Sat Mar 09 00:00:00 GMT 2019}}}</fes:Literal>
 </fes:During>
</fes:Filter>
```

Comment: Yeah, it said `Could not parse CQL filter list. Encountered "DURING P1Y / PRESENT" at line 1, column 11. Was expecting one of: "(" ... ":" ... <IDENTIFIER> ... "." ... "*" ... "/" ... "+" ... "-" ... ")" ... "not" ... "in" ... "tequals" ... "before" ... "after" ... "during" <DATE_TIME> ... "during" <DURATION> "/" <DATE_TIME> ... "during" "or" ... "like" ... "ilike" ... "exists" ... "does-not-exist" ... "is" ... "between" ... "=" ... ">" ... "<" ... ">=" ... "<=" ... "<>" ... Parsing : (temporal DURING P1Y/PRESENT) AND`...